# how to convert text to php or use php in .tpl files

Tags: php, templates

how to convert text to php or use php in .tpl files?

i have this php file

```
<?
$a = "<? echo \"asd\"; ?>";

?>
```

is there eny way to run `<? echo "asd"; ?>` ?

or in .tpl write php code like

```
<? echo "asd"; ?>
```

without smarty

Comment: why do you want to do that ? you should not need that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes:

```
$a = '<? echo "asd"; ?>';
```

Content in single quotes is mostly non-parsed and is outputted as-is.

Edit then if you want to execute $a you would use [eval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php):

```
eval($a);
```

Note from docs:

> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows
>   execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you
>   have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this
>   construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data
>   into it without properly validating it beforehand.